# Cloud Files Meta Data: Any reason to be concerned with custom meta?

Tags: php, rackspace-cloud, cloudfiles

I've been using Rackspace Cloud Files with the PHP API to store uploaded files. The documents are referenced in a local database for easy lookup. All is working well, but I have some concerns with my storage of meta data. I'm storing custom meta data with the Cloud Files via the Rest API.

https://github.com/rackspace/php-cloudfiles

I'm storing some custom name/value pairs in the "meta data" for the cloud file. It seems like the meta data is intended for httpd headers such as Content-Type?

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Is there any problem with storing some custom meta data fields in the cloud files meta data?  For example, I am storing the following so I can find where the document was created from:  'Current-Url', 'Document-Type', 'Original-Name'. I assume it will be fine, as long as it's not already a typical header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their docs:

http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Update_Container_Metadata-d1e1900.html

The only thing you must do is prefix the custom meta data with:

```
X-Container-Meta-
```

There is no problem with storing custom meta data.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see it; X- prefixes are used in many different ways. I assume there will not be any issues as long as the headers don't mean anything to the browser? I'm streaming the cloud files downloads and creating custom http headers with PHP.